# mcrypt seem to be not 100% reversible

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I've 336 'Client' in my database

I tried this code to `encrypt` and then `decrypt` some data

The esit is: Right: 323 - Wrong: 13

**What's the reason because `mcrypt` is not fully reversible ?**

**EDIT: Please don't try to change the nature of the problem, ask to my question or I'll downvote your answers. The problem it's this algorithm seems to be not 100% reversible and this is the problem, THE PROBLEM IS NOT WHY I'M USING IT**

```
        $wrong = $right = 0;

        foreach ($clients as $c) {
            $string_to_encode = trim($c->first_field . ":::" . $c->last_field);

            $mc_key = Yii::app()->params["rijndael_key"];
            $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
            $iv_1 = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
            $crypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $mc_key,
                $string_to_encode,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                $iv_1));
            $token = urlencode(base64_encode($crypt));

            $string_to_decode = base64_decode(urldecode($token));
            $string_decoded = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $mc_key,
                $string_to_decode,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
                $iv_1));


            if ($string_to_encode != $string_decoded) {
                echo $string_to_encode . PHP_EOL;
                echo "***** ERROR ! ***** " . PHP_EOL;
                echo $string_to_encode . PHP_EOL;
                echo $string_decoded . PHP_EOL;
                $wrong ++;
            } else {
                $right ++;
            }

        }

        echo "Right $right - Wrong $wrong" . PHP_EOL;
```

An exmple of differences from plain and decoded string [please note that I changed login name .... ]

```
customer.email@alice.it:::11734
customer.email@alice.it:::11z͉\wo����y�+�   �>�d��x�
```

**The algo is not 100% reversibile. This is the problem, this is the question... obviously I'll not use this in production... it's only a case to demo to YOU that this algo has some problem**

Comment: an encryption algo is either reversible, or isn't. it doesn't arbitrarily decide that only SOME data isn't reversible.

Comment: YES, I know... But this code 100% of times got 'some' not correctly decripted strings. Any idea ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a reversible algorithm for a password anyway. Always use a non-reversible hashing algorithm for passwords.

Comment: are you sure they were encrypted/stored properly in the first place?

Comment: @Spudley : please, check this case and not the goal. I use mcrypt for a lot of things, and this causes me some problems if I cannot be confident It's reversible !!!!

Comment: Perhaps the `trim()` is the cause of your problem? I wouldn't have thought it sensible to be trimming the output of an encryption function.

Comment: As these are fringe cases, I'd suggest that there's something strange happening to those 13 iterations. perhaps there's a storage malfunction or something a little more complex

Comment: @Spudley: this is not the problem, becase decripted string contains "strange chars", so it's not only a problem of trim, but thanks

Comment: @danielhanly.com : storage cannot be the problem, because the difference is beetween 'clear' and decripted strings. I omitted in the code, but the problem is that some 'decripted' strings have "strange chars"

Comment: Is it possible that one of the functions used is failing and returning false, causing later problems? `crypt_create_iv` and `mcrypt_get_iv_size` both can return false on failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Others have mentioned it but you are trimming the results of encryption. The cipher text will appear randomly and some of the items you are encrypting will produce whitespace at the end.

If you trim the cipher text you are losing information and the string will not decode properly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of encrypting your password, **[hash them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)**.

### Advantages:

- PHP(5.5+) has a native API for password hashing and verifying.
- Hashing is always irreversible. If your database gets stolen, an attacker can never get the plain text password directly.
- Proper Hashing+Salting solves 99% of attack vectors on passwords.

Comment: I nee to undertstand this issue, not a workaround or a different solution, but thanks aniway.

Comment: @realtebo: Please come to the PHP room for further explanation. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php. I hope I can change your mind.

Comment: Really don't your care a crypt/decrypt is not 1005 reversibile? It's a big problem for me....

Comment: @realtebo: The difference between **encryption** and **hashing** is that one is reversible, and the other isn't. I'll say it again ***You don't want your password's hash to be reversible!!***. When you need to compare, simply run the user's password through the hash and compare the resulting string. ***NEVER SAVE THE PASSWORD IN REVERSIBLE FORMAT, LET ALONE PLAIN TEXT***. I ask you again, please come to the PHP chat room for more information.

Comment: I know it, please forget it's a password... follow my problem as I was crypting some other data !!!! I know waht's hashing... this is ONLY  A DEMO TO SHOW YOU THE PROBLEM ABOUT MCRYPT !

Answer (score 0):

It's already been addressed that you shouldn't use a two-way encryption algorithm for saving passwords, but instead a one-way hashing algorithm.

You're trimming your data ciphertext. Remove `trim()` around `mcrypt_encrypt()` and you'll be fine.

That said, you have another problem. You generate IVs, but ECB mode doesn't use IVs, so those are useless. A more secure approach to keep your ciphertext more unpredictable is to switch to CBC mode. When you do this, keep in mind that the IVs should be identical when encrypting and decrypting (i.e. `$iv_1` and `$iv_2` should be identical).

Comment: It's not true. But I tried to use $iv_2 = $iv_1 and the result is IDENTICAL . Thanks, your're the first trying to reply to me !

Comment: Well, then something else is wrong, too. But the IVs should definitely be identical, so that is one of your problem.

Comment: Ok, I change the code, so i'm using same iv, but the problem is still here

Comment: @kba This was my first thought but ECB mode doesn't use the IV so it isn't necessary for them to be the same. Mentioned here: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: I see. In that case, `trim()` is definitely the problem.